# Assign values given a table in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe of unique keys and values called df1:

```
df1
Key       Value
Art_1     1342
Art_2     432 
Art_3     42342 
Art_4     3244 
Art_5     6757 
Art_6     432 
....
Art_7262  6757
```

I want to use that table to assign values to df2. It has 1 million entries.

```
df2
Key       Value
Art_1     1342
Art_1     NA 
Art_1     NA 
Art_2     NA 
Art_2     6757 
Art_2     NA 
...
Art_600  NA
Art_600  NA
Art_600  6757
Art_600  6757
...
Art_7262  6757
Art_7262  NA
```

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df2[(df2$key==df1$key[i]),]$value <- df1$value[i]
}
```

It's extremely slow.
The final output should be:

```
df2
Key       Value
Art_1     1342
Art_1     1342 
Art_1     1342 
Art_2     6757 
Art_2     6757 
Art_2     6757 
...
Art_600  6757
Art_600  6757
Art_600  6757
Art_600  6757
...
Art_7262  6757
Art_7262  6757
```

Comment: This is a just a `merge` operation - take a look at the examples here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: My brain completely forgot about merging. crazy

Comment: I was just typing a solution when this got closed as a dupe. Another possibility is `library(zoo); na.locf(df2);` which requires `df2` to have at least one entry for every key (and that the entries are sorted). See `?zoo::na.locf` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wtih tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- left_join(df2$key, df1, by = "Key")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use df1 as a look-up table

```
row.names(df1) = df1$Key
df2$Value = df1$Value[df2$Key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `match` function in the correct order will make things nice and quick for you :)

```
keymatches <- match(df2$Key, df1$Key)
df2$Value <- df1$Value[keyMatches]
```

`match` just returns the position in the vector that it finds the match. So in this case it would return `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)` etc. We then use that as the index for what we want to pull out in `df1`.